# Object does not contain a definition

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to add basic authentication using jquery ajax in my web API project .I followed videos from youtube.I alone got the error.How to rectify it?A snap for your Reference!
The error is :
object does not contain a defintion for 'Any' and no accessible extensible method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'object'  could 'EmployeeService be found

Comment: please show your code. what have you already tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)